# Store procedure não esta funcionando corretamente

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Galera criei uma StoreProcedure denominada, CancelarNota, que através da utilização de cursores, volta os produtos para o estoque, passe o status do item para cancelado. Esta funcionando, porém, não esta setando na coluna [status] o valor de "inativo". Se alguém poder me ajudar!

Esse e o scrip que criei:

```
execute sp_CancelarNota 200200

create procedure sp_CancelarNota(@notafiscal integer)
AS
DECLARE @DATA DATE
DECLARE @VALOR DECIMAL(10,2)
DECLARE @MAT INT
DECLARE @CB INT
DECLARE @QTDITEM DECIMAL(10,2)
DECLARE @STATUS CHAR(1)

DECLARE cVendas CURSOR
FAST_FORWARD 
FOR SELECT DATA, VALOrNOTA, MAT FROM NOTaFISCAL
WHERE NUMNF = @notafiscal
OPEN cVendas
FETCH NEXT FROM cVendas INTO @DATA, @VALOR, @MAT
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
    UPDATE PRODUTO SET QTDeATUAL = QTDeATUAL+@QTDITEM
    WHERE CB = @CB
    FETCH NEXT FROM cVendas INTO @CB, @QTDITEM
END

DELETE FROM NOTaFISCAL WHERE
NOTaFISCAL.NUMNF = @notafiscal
DELETE FROM ITENsNOTA WHERE
ITENsNOTA.NUMNF = @notafiscal
INSERT INTO NOTaFISCAL (STATUS) WHERE NUMNF = 100100 VALUES('INATIVO');

CLOSE cVendas
DEALLOCATE cVendas
```

Comment: Se o intuito é atualizar o campo STATUS da tabela NOTaFISCAL, para a NUMNF = 100100, o comando não seria INSERT e sim UPDATE.

Comment: e verdade...vou tentar!!!

Comment: @Brenin_rice: Na tabela ITENSNOTA qual é o nome da coluna que contém o código do produto? E qual o nome da coluna que contém a quantidade de itens vendidos, do produto? // Na tabela PRODUTO qual é o nome da coluna que contém o código do produto?

Comment: ITENSNOTA a coluna e CB uma FK.  e o nome da coluna de itens vendidos e QTDeVEND. na tabela PRODUTO a coluna e CB uma PK.

Answer (score -1):

Pelo o que pude ver, você está fazendo um DELETE antes, e depois um INSERT, logo, dependendo de como estão os dados os dados, isso faz a vez de um UPDATE.

Porém, o INSERT está sendo feito com o NUMNF fixo no valor de 100100, além de estar na sintaxe errada, acredito que deveria estar recebendo a variável @notafiscal. Portanto o trecho de código deve ser alterado para isto abaixo:

```
INSERT INTO NOTaFISCAL (NUMNF, STATUS) VALUES (@notafiscal, 'INATIVO');
```

Corrija o INSERT para atender as colunas necessárias.

Answer (score -1):

Me parece que o código necessita ser reescrito.

O cursor `cVendas` está declarado para ler linha na tabela `NOTAFISCAL` e retornar as colunas`DATA`, `VALORNOTA` e `MAT`. No primeiro FETCH o uso do cursor está correto, carregando os respectivos valores nas variáveis @DATA, @VALOR e @MAT. Já no FETCH interno ao loop (instrução WHILE), ele carrega as variáveis @CB e @QTDITEM que, me parece, não tem qualquer relação com as colunas `DATA`, `VALORNOTA` e `MAT`.

Outro erro percebido é que a instrução UPDATE, dentro do loop, tem a seguinte restrição na cláusula WHERE:

```
WHERE CB = @CB
```

Entretanto, a variável @CB está sem nada assinalado para ela, na primeira execução; isto é, está NULL.

Também é estranho que a linha contendo a nota fiscal seja apagada da tabela NOTAFISCAL se é necessário alterar o STATUS para 'INATIVO'.

---

Com as informações fornecidas até o momento, eis esboço de sugestão de código para cancelamento de nota fiscal.

```
-- código #1 v2
CREATE PROCEDURE CancelarNota
       @notafiscal integer

begin

-- analisa parâmetro
IF @notafiscal is null 
  return -1;  -- erro: número de nota fiscal não informado

IF not exists (SELECT * from NOTAFISCAL
                 where NUMNF = @notafiscal)
  return -2;  -- erro: não existe a nota fiscal

IF (SELECT STATUS from NOTAFISCAL
      where NUMNF = @notafiscal) = 'INATIVO'
  return -3;  -- erro: nota fiscal está inativa

--
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- estorna quantidade de itens de cada produto
UPDATE P
  set QTDEATUAL= QTDEATUAL + IN.QTDEVEND
  from PRODUTO as P
       inner join ITENSNOTA as IN on IN.CB = P.CB
  where IN.NUMNF = @notafiscal;

-- apaga itens da venda
DELETE ITENSNOTA 
  where NUMNF = @notafiscal;

-- marca a nota fiscal como inválida
UPDATE NOTAFISCAL
  set STATUS = 'INATIVO'
  where NUMNF = @notafiscal;

COMMIT;

return 0;   -- ok!
end;
go
```

Comment: @Brenin_rice: Quando possível, verifique se o código #1 v2 acima atende ao que necessita. Atualizei com os nomes de colunas que informou.